# How does pipenv decide my python version and why does the requirement.txt generated different from the original?

Tags: python, pipenv

How does pipenv decide my python version? My default python3 version is different from the version pipenv decided. A simple example to illustrate my problem. Pipefile said 3.8 while my python3 is 3.9.

```
pyenv_test ➤ cat requirements.txt                                
pexpect==4.8.0
termcolor==1.1.0
pyenv_test ➤ pipenv install                            
requirements.txt found, instead of Pipfile! Converting...
✔ Success!
Warning: Your Pipfile now contains pinned versions, if your requirements.txt did.
We recommend updating your Pipfile to specify the "*" version, instead.
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success!
Updated Pipfile.lock (a46966)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a46966)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
pyenv_test ➤ cat Pipfile                     
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pexpect = "==4.8.0"
termcolor = "==1.1.0"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
pyenv_test ➤ which python3              
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

Another problem I found is the requirement.text it generated was different from the one created Pipefile in the first place.

```
pyenv_test ➤ pipenv lock -r   
#
# These requirements were autogenerated by pipenv
# To regenerate from the project's Pipfile, run:
#
#    pipenv lock --requirements
#

-i https://pypi.org/simple
pexpect==4.8.0
ptyprocess==0.6.0
termcolor==1.1.0
```

Comparing with my requirements.txt that generated the Pipefile in the first place it added ptyprocess. As the comment pointed out ptyprocess is used by pexpect. But why did Pipefile add that as another requirement.

Comment: https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess?

Comment: Oh that make sense then. But still, it is pexpect's dependence, so it should not be list in requirement.txt

Comment: Update my question based on what you found.

Comment: because you have it in requirements.txt: pexpect==4.8.0 ... and again read the core idea of pipenv https://kenreitz.org/essays/a-better-pip-workflow

Comment: How about you just said my question ? And what the python version problem ?

Comment: what is the output of `python3 --version` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225150/discussion-between-qiulang-and-madzohan).

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the `pipenv` docs on [specifying a python version](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#specifying-versions-of-python) it states:

> If you don’t specify a Python version on the command–line, either the [requires] `python_full_version` or `python_version` will be selected automatically, falling back to whatever your system’s default python installation is, at time of execution.

My guess is you initialized your `pipenv` project before you upgraded to python 3.9.

If you do want to update your `Pipfile` to specify your specific version of python you can simply:

```sh
pipenv --python 3.9
```

You can of course also manually update the `python_version` in your `Pipfile`.

Comment: I am afraid it is not that the case because I run pip3 install pipenv couple days ago to install pipenv under python 3.9

Comment: Interesting, I just confirmed that after installing python 3.9.0 and `pipenv` via `pip3 install pipenv`, and running `pipenv install` my `Pipfile` states `python_version = "3.9"`. Do you have any other python versions installed?

Comment: I do have 3.8 in /usr/local/bin/python3.8 but I am using 3.9. After checking the comments I got and I did some other testing. I am thinking it is a bug. So I have raised an issue https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4546

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps it finds 3.8 on your `PATH` before it finds 3.9? Regardless, the issue you raised is likely to be more fruitful in giving you an answer!

Comment: Because I am not familiar with pipenv I had thought maybe it was something I did wrong so I did not raise the issue first. I hope I can get some reply for my issue.

Comment: Hi I got some reply. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue against pipenv https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4546, after discussing with one of maintainers, I now understood why my problem happened.

For my first issue, when run `pipenv install` pipenv reused the existing one which was python 3.8, i.e. venv is not recreated. I feel it looks like a problem, why reuse a venv on a new project?

For my second issue, it does help me understand what does "**produce deterministic builds**" mean. ptyprocess is used by pexpect. I check pexpect's setup.py https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/setup.py

```
install_requires=['ptyprocess>=0.5'],
```

So by specifying `ptyprocess==0.6.0 & pexpect==4.8.0` in requirement.txt does produce deterministic build.